# Visual Studio Online - Shared Projects

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I have added a new solution to VSO and would like to reference a project already belonging to a different solution.
As an example I have a solution that contains common/core framework code.
I then want to be able to create new solutions that reference this common code.
Does anybody know the best way to achieve this? or if it is possible?

Comment: Is the common code that you want to share or the functionality of the common code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it but it is extremely bad practice and often leads to issues.

You can simply add any Project inside of the same source control repository to any solution. Having the code under the solution will make it flow better and cause less issues. (However this is high on my list of silly things customers do that I have to undo)

The real solution however is to have a solution for your shared , and package it as a Nuget package, then publish it to a local (myget is best) repository. You can then add that Nuget package to as many projects as you like.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way for you to add reference to project (source code) in another solution, because, you can only add reference to project that in the same solution.

You can, however, first compile the common framework code to generate the common.dll, for example. Then add reference to the common.dll in the new solution. If the common framework code is stable that doesn't change, you can just put the common.dll into source control, with this way to be sure that the referenced dll file can be found when build in VSO.